# Why is DAO defined as fun in RoomDatabase?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In Android sample codes/codelabs, Daos inside RoomDatabase are defined as

```
abstract fun genericDao(): GenericDao
```

and when you need to access the dao's methods, you call

```
database.genericDao().genericFun()
```

Why is it implemented like this, and not like

```
abstract val genericDao: GenericDao
database.genericDao.genericFun()
```

? Is it wrong to do it the second way?

[Link to Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i checked Decompiled bytecode and the only difference is that first implementation is named as

```
subscriptionStatusDao()
```

and the second one as

```
getSubscriptionStatusDao()
```

So basically, no difference at all.